# Remove exim local username

Tags: email, debian, exim, debian-squeeze

How can i remove the local username in the mail headers with exim4 running on debian 6?

```
Received: from root by host.domain.com with local (Exim 4.72)
(envelope-from <reply@domain.com>)
id 123123123
for user@gmail.com; Tue, 03 Jan 2012 13:08:17 +0100
```

So I want to remove the part with root and the local hostname together(?).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to modify `received_header_text` as per [the documentation](http://www.exim.org/exim-html-current/doc/html/spec_html/ch14.html).

It defaults to:

```
received_header_text = Received: \
  ${if def:sender_rcvhost {from $sender_rcvhost\n\t}\
  {${if def:sender_ident \
  {from ${quote_local_part:$sender_ident} }}\
  ${if def:sender_helo_name {(helo=$sender_helo_name)\n\t}}}}\
  by $primary_hostname \
  ${if def:received_protocol {with $received_protocol}} \
  ${if def:tls_cipher {($tls_cipher)\n\t}}\
  (Exim $version_number)\n\t\
  ${if def:sender_address \
  {(envelope-from <$sender_address>)\n\t}}\
  id $message_exim_id\
  ${if def:received_for {\n\tfor $received_for}}
```

After modification it'll be:

```
  received_header_text = Received: \
  by $primary_hostname \
  ${if def:received_protocol {with $received_protocol}} \
  ${if def:tls_cipher {($tls_cipher)\n\t}}\
  (Exim $version_number)\n\t\
  ${if def:sender_address \
  {(envelope-from <$sender_address>)\n\t}}\
  id $message_exim_id\
  ${if def:received_for {\n\tfor $received_for}}

  (IT IS WORKING CODE)
```

Comment: Thank you. In my split-configuration i had to add these lines to a file in the main dir.

Comment: This does not work in Debian 6.0.5. It yields a string expansion error, trying to sort out why.