# Hide server ip from email header

Tags: email, smtp, ip, email-server, smtp-headers

I use ddos mitigation services on my server and due to this it is very important that my server ip stays hidden. I own two servers, the primary server houses my website and the secondary server is used for emails. I use the secondary servers smtp info to send email. The problem is that the secondary server adds the ip address of the primary server in the email headers.

```
x-store-info:J++/JTCzmObr++wNraA4Pa4f5Xd6uensydyekesGC2M=
Authentication-Results: hotmail.com; spf=none (sender IP is 62.62.622.62) smtp.mailfrom=; dkim=none header.d=mywebsite.com; x-hmca=none
X-SID-PRA: 
X-AUTH-Result: NONE
X-SID-Result: NONE
X-Message-Status: n:n
X-Message-Delivery: Vj0xLjE7dXM9MDtsPTE7YT0xO0Q9MTtHRD0xO1NDTD0x
X-Message-Info: aKlYzGSc+LkUh5O0AnwOe0N6RG7BEHXa+Ep9dVv2J/KLBdwJ4Iby2lXjCPbTQYFQteOst4AFBmvouIk6oSlsys3EmGNQAosOELxkPAlgXi6poOzgrzcwdKVa0O5X7ZL8AcJld8q/XqwGrh9m5oeIOUZC7Cl4wZMX
Received: from mail.secondaryserver.com ([62.62.622.62]) by COL0-MC4-F28.Col0.hotmail.com with Microsoft SMTPSVC(6.0.3790.4900);
     Tue, 25 Dec 2012 20:42:38 -0800
Received: from [199.199.199.199] (port=59186 helo=localhost)
    by mail.secondaryserver.com with esmtpsa (TLSv1:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:256)
    (Exim 4.80)
    (envelope-from )
    id 1TnipC-0001XL-4D
    for ; Tue, 25 Dec 2012 22:42:38 -0600
To: Test E-Mail 
Subject: Test E-Mail Message
Date: Wed, 26 Dec 2012 05:42:37 +0100
From: mywebsite 
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
Content-Disposition: inline
MIME-Version: 1.0
X-AntiAbuse: This header was added to track abuse, please include it with any abuse report
X-AntiAbuse: Primary Hostname - mail.secondaryserver.com
X-AntiAbuse: Original Domain - live.com
X-AntiAbuse: Originator/Caller UID/GID - [47 12] / [47 12]
X-AntiAbuse: Sender Address Domain - mywebsite.com
X-BWhitelist: no
X-Source: 
X-Source-Args: 
X-Source-Dir: 
X-Source-Sender: (localhost) [199.199.199.199]:59186
X-Source-Auth: emailacc
X-Email-Count: 0
X-Source-Cap: ZW1haWx0bWM7dG1jYmxvZ3M7dGVtcGxlLndlYnNpdGV3ZWxjb21lLmNvbQ==
Return-Path: 
Message-ID: 
X-OriginalArrivalTime: 26 Dec 2012 04:42:38.0526 (UTC) FILETIME=[6EC335E0:01CDE323]
```

In this header the ip address 62.62.622.62 belongs to the secondary server and the ip address 199.199.199.199 belongs to the primary server. I want to remove all occurrences of 199.199.199.199 from this header and replace them with 62.62.622.62.

Answer (score 2):

in EXIM changes to **Received** header string can be made via **received_header_text** variable

[Remove exim local username](https://serverfault.com/questions/346102/remove-exim-local-username)

Comment: So if I don't assign anything to it, that should solve the problem.