# Remove IP and username from Exim mail headers

Tags: email-server, exim

I have an Exim4 running on Debian which I use for transactional emails from my other servers protected by CloudFlare. Every transactional email sent from it has an IP address of the sender (1.2.3.4) and an SMTP username (smtp_user@mailserver.com) in mail headers, and I would like to hide or replace them:

```
Received: from CF-protected-domain.com ([1.2.3.4]) 
by mailserver.com with esmtpsa (TLS1.3:ECDHE_RSA_AES_256_GCM_SHA384:256) (Exim 4.92) 
(envelope-from <smtp_user@mailserver.com>) id 1kL3QG-0000Ew-9p for recipient@email.com; 
Wed, 23 Sep 2020 14:58:56 +0300
Date: Wed, 23 Sep 2020 07:58:54 -0400
From: "#Site name" <no-reply@CF-protected-domain.com>
```

Any chance I can remove or replace IP-address (1.2.3.4) with the mail server's IP address (e.g. 7.8.9.0)? And replace envelope-from with the "From: " email address (no-reply@CF-protected-domain.com)? Like this:

```
Received: from CF-protected-domain.com ([7.8.9.0]) 
by mailserver.com with esmtpsa (TLS1.3:ECDHE_RSA_AES_256_GCM_SHA384:256) (Exim 4.92) 
(envelope-from <no-reply@CF-protected-domain.com>) id 1kL3QG-0000Ew-9p for recipient@email.com; 
Wed, 23 Sep 2020 14:58:56 +0300
Date: Wed, 23 Sep 2020 07:58:54 -0400
From: "#Site name" <no-reply@CF-protected-domain.com>
```

Comment: Use a third party mail service such as sendgrid, mailgun, etc.

Comment: Not every 3rd party service hides the sender's IP. E.g. I am currently using smtp.com and they don't modify headers. Anyway, my own mail server is a plan B just in case so I want to set it up.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to remove `Received` header by adding the following to `/etc/exim4/exim4.conf.localmacros`:

```
REMOTE_SMTP_TRANSPORTS_HEADERS_REMOVE = Received
```

With this setting, Exim4 no longer leaks my IP address to recipients.

Comment: Any references or documentation about this? It's not on my system and I can't find that string in the current Exim source code.

Comment: the above feature is debian only,   if no debian use `headers_remove = received` in the aproproriate SMTP transport

Comment: @ygoe see `/etc/exim/conf.d/transport/30_exim4-config_remote_smtp` and `/etc/exim/conf.d/transport/30_exim4-config_remote_smtp_smarthost` - search for `REMOTE_SMTP_TRANSPORTS_HEADERS_REMOVE` in those files